# xcode after adding folder to project .h not found

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, adwhirl

I am developing cocos2d app and was trying to add adwhirl into it.
I downloaded AdWhirl sdk and added to project (pulled folder to column where are all .h .m files, checked add to target and copy files). But after I add for example

```
#import "AdWhirlDelegateProtocol.h"
```

I get an error like this AdWhirlDelegateProtocol.h file not found

Comment: Build Settings -> Header Search Paths

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that `AdWhirlDelegateProtocol.h` is actually linked in your project (you should be able to find it on the left in XCode under the AdWhirl folder).

After that, you probably want to look at the `Library Search Paths` under `Build Settings` to make sure that it's pointing to the right path where all your AdWhirl files are.

You can also check the `Header Search Paths` under `Build Settings` to make sure that isn't pointing anywhere it shouldn't be as well.